# Divergence of first Piola-Kirchoff stress tensor: how is it computed?

Tags: mathematical-physics, tensors, divergence-operator, cylindrical-coordinates

studying the bending of an incompressible elastic block of Neo-Hookean material, one finds out the first Piola-Kirchoff stress tensor

$$S=\left(\frac{\pi + \mu_0}{\lambda_1} + \mu_0 \lambda_1\!\right)e_r \otimes e_1 + \left(\frac{\pi + \mu_0}{\lambda_2} + \mu_0 \lambda_2\!\right) e_\theta \otimes e_2$$

[see page 182 (equation 5.93)](https://books.google.it/books?id=f3RrYLujw8oC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=Finite%20bending%20of%20an%20incompressible%20elastic%20block&source=bl&ots=hDKzQSjxSv&sig=ACfU3U3fLyBQ9a3XuAl14bfvVHTrmfKs6Q&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi61bzqxLfwAhVGi6QKHcWEBt8Q6AEwCXoECAUQAw#v=onepage&q=Finite%20bending%20of%20an%20incompressible%20elastic%20block&f=false)

where $e_r = cos(\theta)e_1 + \sin(\theta)e_2$ and $e_{\theta} = -sin(\theta)e_1 + \cos(\theta)e_2$

How is the divergence defined in this case? The book writes the following

$$Div(S) = \frac{\partial }{\partial x_1^0} S_{r1} e_r + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2^0} S_{\theta 2} e_{\theta} = 0$$

but I can't see why this is the divergence of $S$. I'd like to have a formal proof of this. I know that, by definition, the divergence of a tensor field $S$ is the unique vector field such that

$Div(S^T a)=Div(S) \cdot a$

for every vector $a$